# GCC -T link option issue

Tags: gcc, linker, arm, ld

I have compiled the project with arm-none-eabi-gcc to object with command

```
arm-none-eabi-gcc --specs=nosys.specs -mcpu=cortex-m7 -mtune=cortex-m7 -Os -g -gdwarf-2  -c $< -o $(@)
```

currently I got the object file when I try to link it with command in object foler

```
arm-none-eabi-gcc --specs=nosys.specs -mcpu=cortex-m7 -mtune=cortex-m7  -g -gdwarf-2  -nostartfiles -T ..\project.ld  -o target *
```

However I got some strange error

```
arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: error: no memory region specified for loadable section `.text.memcmp'
```

I understand that when I use -T option the link script file will be used instead of default link script. it looks like the section definitions for some builtin function are missing. I tried to fix that put

```
.text.memcmp : {*(.text.memcmp)}
```

in my ld file, it looks like this section is fixed however I got another error:

```
arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: error: no memory region specified for loadable section `.text.memset'
```

so I don't think put .text.memset in the LD file is correct fix, because after I put `.text.memset' in ld file , I got another error :

```
arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: error: no memory region specified for loadable section `.text._snprintf_r'
```

I think I missed some options in GCC to create these default sections for builtin functions

What is the root cause of this issue and how to fix that? Thank you so much!

Update: Add the LD file below :

```
MEMORY {
  INIT_SRAM                : ORIGIN = 0x34400000, LENGTH = 0x1FB000
  INIT_SRAM_NO_CACHEABLE   : ORIGIN = 0x3460A000, LENGTH = 0x1DF00
  INIT_SRAM_STACK          : ORIGIN = 0x34628000, LENGTH = 0x15000
  RAM_RSVD               : ORIGIN = .,          LENGTH = 0
  BOOT_TEST           : ORIGIN = 0x43840000  LENGTH = 0x50    
}
SECTIONS 
{
.boot_test                                         : {*(.boot_test)}> BOOT_TEST 
.exception_table                             ALIGN(4)   : > {*(.exception_table)}>INIT_SRAM
.startup                                     ALIGN(4)   : {*(.startup)}
.ramcode                                    ALIGN(4) : > {*(.ramcode)} 
.text ALIGN(4) : { *(.text) }
.ramcode                                     ALIGN(4) : { *(.ramcode) }
.rodata                                     ALIGN(4)    : { *(.rodata) }
.data                                     ALIGN(4)      : { *(.data) }
.bss                                 ALIGN(16)  : { *(.bss) }

_TEST_SESSION_START = .;
.TEST_SESSION :{*(.TEST_SESSION)}
_TEST_SESSION_END = (. - 1);  

_Stack_start                       = .;
__STACK_SIZE                     = SIZEOF(INIT_SRAM_STACK);
__RAM_NO_CACHEABLE_START      = ADDR(INIT_SRAM_NO_CACHEABLE);

}
```

Comment: Thanks -  would you have a very, very  minimal C program to provide that would trigger the problem on your side?

Answer (score 2):

Changing

```
.text ALIGN(4) : { *(.text) }
```

to

```
.text ALIGN(4) : { *(.text) *(.text.*) }
```

can fix this .text.xxx missing issue.